# Python code swaps csv columns when used 3 times in the row ( 3 consecutive days)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-os

Received a huge help in figuring out the code for web-scraping particular website with tender opportunities ( for college project). Decided to apply this code for other data but ran into a problem. On a third run ( 3rd day) csv file generated swaps columns compared to their initial order, put index numbers ( *could not figure out how to to stop it* ) and does not write new data on the 4th day.

**Goal:**

- Web-scrape data that is getting updated everyday with new entries *(past day data is getting deleted)*.
- Generating CSV file ( EXCEL preferred) for historic records with specific order of columns and types of info inside them (I know how to change order for headers).

Tried to change code so it created excel ( nothing happens). And that is it. Beside that I just manually copy paste new data ( which is not efficient and that is why I was trying to get the code do it for me. Do not know how to fix the indexing ( I do not need it to appear after 3rd run).

```````````
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os

filename = "BuyandSell_V3.csvs"

# Initialize an empty 'results' dataframe
results = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterarte through the pages
for page in range(0,20):
    url = 'https://buyandsell.gc.ca/procurement-data/search/site?page=' + str(page) + '&f%5B0%5D=sm_facet_procurement_data%3Adata_data_tender_notice&f%5B1%5D=dds_facet_date_published%3Adds_facet_date_published_today'

    page_html = requests.get(url).text
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"rc"})

    # Get data from each container
    if containers != []:
        for each in containers:
            title = each.find('h2').text.strip()
            publication_date = each.find('dd', {'class':'data publication-date'}).text.strip()
            closing_date = each.find('dd', {'class':'data date-closing'}).text.strip()
            gsin = each.find('dd', {'class':'data gsin'}).text.strip()
            notice_type = each.find('dd', {'class':'data php'}).text.strip()
            procurement_entity = each.find('dd', {'data procurement-entity'}).text.strip()
        

            # Create 1 row dataframe
            temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[title, publication_date, closing_date, gsin, notice_type, procurement_entity]], columns = ['Title', 'Publication Date', 'Closing Date', 'GSIN', 'Notice Type', 'Procurement Entity'])

            # Append that row to a 'results' dataframe
            results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
        print ('Aquired page ' + str(page+1))

    else:
        print ('No more pages')
        break


# If already have a file saved
if os.path.isfile(filename):

    # Read in previously saved file
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    # Append the newest results
    df = df.append(results).reset_index()

    # Drop and duplicates (incase the newest results aren't really new)
    df = df.drop_duplicates()

    # Save the previous file, with appended results
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)

else:

    # If a previous file not already saved, save a new one
    df = results.copy()
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)

`````` 
Expected results - parsed data into csv format with headers defined. CSV being refreshed after each run ( new day - new data to parse). 

Preferred - data is written to excel ( tried to do it but nothing happens).
``````````
```````````

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to write as excel file instead of csv, change to:

```
filename = "BuyandSell_V3.xls"

df = pd.read_excel(filename)

df.to_excel(filename, index=False)
```

to not have the index in your columns, you need to drop those when you reset the index (which you did earlier with your `results` dataframe, but not later:

```
df = df.append(results).reset_index(drop=True)
```

As far as the other issues, I'm not quite sure what you are describing or happening that it's not working on the 4th day and/or the columns are swapped.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

filename = "BuyandSell_V3.xls"

# Initialize an empty 'results' dataframe
results = pd.DataFrame()


# Iterarte through the pages
for page in range(0,20):
    url = 'https://buyandsell.gc.ca/procurement-data/search/site?page=' + str(page) + '&f%5B0%5D=sm_facet_procurement_data%3Adata_data_tender_notice&f%5B1%5D=dds_facet_date_published%3Adds_facet_date_published_today'

    page_html = requests.get(url).text
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"rc"})

    # Get data from each container
    if containers != []:
        for each in containers:
            title = each.find('h2').text.strip()
            publication_date = each.find('dd', {'class':'data publication-date'}).text.strip()
            closing_date = each.find('dd', {'class':'data date-closing'}).text.strip()
            gsin = each.find('dd', {'class':'data gsin'}).text.strip()
            notice_type = each.find('dd', {'class':'data php'}).text.strip()
            procurement_entity = each.find('dd', {'data procurement-entity'}).text.strip()


            # Create 1 row dataframe
            temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[title, publication_date, closing_date, gsin, notice_type, procurement_entity]], columns = ['Title', 'Publication Date', 'Closing Date', 'GSIN', 'Notice Type', 'Procurement Entity'])

            # Append that row to a 'results' dataframe
            results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
        print ('Aquired page ' + str(page+1))

    else:
        print ('No more pages')
        break


# If already have a file saved
if os.path.isfile(filename):

    # Read in previously saved file
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)

    # Append the newest results
    df = df.append(results).reset_index(drop=True)

    # Drop and duplicates (incase the newest results aren't really new)
    df = df.drop_duplicates()

    # Save the previous file, with appended results
    df.to_excel(filename, index=False)

else:

    # If a previous file not already saved, save a new one
    df = results.copy()
    df.to_excel(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: Hello @chitown88, so i used the code for 3 days straight and on the 3rd day, columns are getting mixed up. I changed order myself ( see below )  ~~~    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[procurement_entity, title, publication_date, closing_date, link]], columns = ['Procurement Entity','Title','Publication Date', 'Closing Date', 'Link']) ~~~ It works perfectly for 2 day straight, but on the 3rd day, order goes as follows : Closing date, Link, Entity, Publication Date, Title, Index and then column called Level_0 ( have no idea what is it). Can you advise on how I could fix it?

Comment: That is weird. I’ll have to try and see why that is.

Comment: So When I applied your drop=True for append results, this is when another column with numbers appear. I did not use this change for first 2 days. This happened first time you helped me with the script and now. The only changes were your drop=True and I changed the sequence of columns.

Comment: Oh yes. If you don’t have drop=True, it’ll add a column